# Is the Google Analytics "UA-" prefix gone for properties

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I just created a new property in Google Analytics and was looking for the property ID, in this format: UA-xxxxxxx-y
I can only find a number 9 digit number.
Is the format changed since Google Analytics G4?

I'm following this guide and I'm looking for the Tracking ID they mention: [Setmore Setup Guide](https://support.setmore.com/en/articles/490934-google-analytics)

Answer (score 4):

The Property creation process now defaults to GA4 (formerly known as app+web) Properties.

If you want to create a Universal (formerly known as web) Property,
goto the Admin page where it lists your GA Account and the existing GA4 Property.

Click the +Create new property button at the top of the property column.

Once on the new Property Settings page, select the blue link *Show advanced options* to see and toggle on the Universal property options.

Select create Universal Property only.
[image]

Then click Next and complete the Property creation.

You will then be able to access the Universal gtag.js tracking code snippet via the Tracking Info section in the Property column and your UA-XXXX tracking Id will be on the top of the Property Settings page.

Answer (score 3):

Google Analytics 4 doesn't have property ids it has MEASUREMENT_ID which is just a 9 digit number.